# How to read the information in configuration files(.properties) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, I need to get data from configuration file(.properties) .My configuration file looks something like this(.properties):

```
maxTime = 60
upVotePostMaxTime=60
```

but I don't know how to read the configuration file in JavaScript. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: where is this "file" located? Are you using something like Node where your javascript is running on a server and can deal with the File system? Or are you just wishfully thinking about having it do this in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advisable to read configuration files from JavaScript. Instead you could do this:

1. Read the file on server-side (using PHP, .Net or Python or any other language that you prefer)
2. Render the valid values to JavaScript. Something like:

   `var maxTime = "<?php echo maxTime; ?>";`

   `var upVotePostMaxTime = "<?php echo upVotePostMaxTime; ?>";`

where `<?php echo maxTime; ?>` and `<?php echo upVotePostMaxTime; ?>` will have values `60` each.
This would show on the client-side as:

```
var maxTime = "60";
var upVotePostMaxTime = "60";
```

and then you may use it in JavaScript.

> Values are assigned in double quotes to prevent breaking of JavaScript code in case `null` values are sent from the server.
>
> Please ensure that proper values are assigned to JavaScript variables.

Comment: Another way would be to use ajax for passing the variables to js

Comment: @MateiMihai, that could be another way of implementing what I have suggested. Render it directly or use AJAX, the logic is same...read configuration on server-side and return to client-side.